# Query DynamoDB ISO-8601 Date index with less than condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

I have a DynamoDB Index storing a date in iso-8601 format, [i.e. '2017-03-17']. I'd like to query the Index for dates less than a certain date. [i.e datetime.now() - 30 days].

I believe this is support from looking at Amazon's API docs. I seem to be missing something with the boto3 syntax.

I am using the resource and not the client in boto3.

I know I can use epoch but would like to use the ISO format for readability.

Here is the test code I have.

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
_table = ddb.Table('TableWithDateIndex')

response2 = _table.query(
    IndexName='DeleteDate-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('IndexDate').lt('2017-04-17')
)

print response2['Items']
```

Fails with:

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So IndexDate is a hash key of your 'DeleteDate-index' index. When using Query, **you must provide an equality condition for hash key**, i.e. `.eq()`. In other words, you can't use comparison operators like `lt`, `lte`, `gt`, `gte` etc. with a hash key in Query. In a KeyConditionExpression these operators can only be applied to a range key.

Here is an excerpt from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query):

> In a Query operation, you use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to
>   determine the items to be read from the table or index.  You must
>   specify the partition key name and value as an equality condition. You
>   can optionally provide a second condition for the sort key (if
>   present).

---

You can use Scan operation instead of Query. When running Scan, you are allowed to use any operators on any fields in FilterExpression (or do not use any conditions at all). Though you should use Scan with caution since it can be a very heavyweight operation: it implies reading every item in a table (or a secondary index).